# How secure is the "if" statement?

Tags: security, if-statement, logic

Regardless of the language I'm always puzzled by the concept of security through an `if`. All the code I write relies on success of that one line with  `if` statement:

```
user = getUserName();
password = getPassword();

if (match(user, password)) {
    print secret information;
}
```

Since it's only one line I feel like sabotage can be relatively simple. Am I overlooking things, or is a single `if` really the best way to do this?

Comment: "Sabotage"? If an attacker has write access to the source code, you're screwed³ in any case. Besides, what would be the alternative? Making the whole logic so convoluted and obfuscated that neither attacker not maintainer can comprehend it? And even then, any serious attacker *will* work through any obfuscation and complex security schemes - just look at piracy of music, movies, video games etc.

Comment: No, I'm asking about attack from the outside.

Comment: And how can an attacker attack your code without having access to it?

Comment: @svick You don't need the code for that. I assume you have heard of cracked software that can be installed without a registration key? Well this is how that's done. No one had the actual code of that software.

Comment: @svick, you're comfortable thinking that your savings account is protected by one line with an `if` statement?

Comment: @GolezTrol, except when you run any application on your computer you do have access to the code. Not the source in the language it was written in, but assembly (or CIL, Java byte code, …) is code too.

Comment: What GolezTrol was noting is that you can manipulate data that is used by the code without having access to the code itself. Web examples include SQL injection, or global variables

Comment: @Mikhail, I hope my savings account is not protected by one line, but by a team of people who understand security deeply and reviewed all the relevant code.

Comment: @svick, in that case you agree that my question holds valid concern.

Comment: I think you have to be more specific in your question. If the attacker doesn't have access to neither the source code OR the compiled code, then the statement in itself is "safe". For situations where the attacker has access to the secret information (e.g. if he has a compiled application containing the secret information) then the if statment isn't safe of course. He could just manipulate the compiled application to bypass the if statement. In such a situation you would want the information to be encrypted.

Comment: I for one have the same hope as @svick, but I also wouldn't be surprised if at the end, after SSL and encryption and hashing and salting and sacrificing a goat to repel the evil attackers, the decision whether access to my bank account is granted or not is implemented using an `if` statement, and these experts rightfully consider the whole thing safe. I don't think there's anything special about an `if` - you *gotta* branch *somehow* by definition, be it through an `if`, polymorphism, or even a clever indirect jump. It's about whether the decision itself (the condition) can be manipulated.

Comment: I don't think you understand the basics of secuirty.   Its really a problem of taint's and sinks,  not conditionals.

Comment: @Rook, sounds like you have more to say.... post a real answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the specific case you are showing, if you were really worried about unauthorized people seeing the secret information output by "print secret information;" you would encrypt the "secret information" with the supplied password.  This would ensure that only the person who was able to provide the proper password would be able to see the secret information.

Comment: +1 because it addressed my exact concern about the power of `if`

Answer (score 5):

You are right, an `if` like this is easily hacked. If one reverse engineers this application, you can easily modify a few instructions to skip the `if`.

There are various options, like obfuscating the executable or adding more complex checks and in add them in various places in your application. But whatever you do, your application can always be hacked.

Best thing is not to worry about it. By the time your application is so good and great and widely used that people are actually willing to put effort in cracking it, you will probably make enough money to protect it better. Until then, it's a waste of time to even think about it.

Comment: A rather comforting answer. +1 and a pat on the back

Answer (score 2):

There's one thing about IF's that is often overlooked. It's called timing attack. Suppose you have a web application that does comparison based on direct matching of password sent against password stored in the DB (yes, I know that nobody in his mind will store passwords in the DB, but as Cheshire Cat said, "we are all mad here"). Then comparison procedure takes different time depending on whether the passwords don't match on the first character, on the second one or on the last one. While it might seem that the time difference is tiny, it's enough for attacker to attempt to guess the password even across internet, not talking about local analysis. Timing attack is a bit more complicated, than I described, but in general IF comparison is not 100% safe, at least not in all cases.

Comment: Never thought about it :) Not really applicable anywhere I can image, but a nice trick to have in your pocket

Comment: @Mikhail I am afraid it's more applicable than one would thought. I.e. it's not just theoretical.

Comment: Oh I understand :) I was imagining cases where I could apply it today. On my server if there's a user/pass mismatch I issue a 4 second delay

Comment: @Mikhail delay should be random. Constant delay adds no security to counteracting such attacks. Instead of time X you just get X + 4000.

Answer (score 2):

The if statement is absolutely secure,  and can never be the cause of a vulnerability.   Vulnerabilities arise from nearly everything else in your code.

It is possible that the comparison operator that you are using is flawed.   For instance the `==` operator employs fuzzing matching where a [range of possible values](http://www.blueshoes.org/en/developer/php_cheat_sheet) are accepted.  This might not be good for secuirty but its hard to come up with a good example,  it doesn't really matter for a password.  A simple `$password==$_GET['password']` should work just fine.

Your if statement could also be relying on bad regular expression such as

```php
if(preg_match('/(.+)\\.js/'.$_GET['file'])){
    readfile($_GET['file']);
}
```

In this case the regex is looking for a .js anywhere in the string,  not enforcing it to be at the end.

```
?file=../../.js/../../../../../../../etc/passwd
```

(And this vulnerability won me $3,000 in the Mozilla bug bounty program ;)

Comment: I recall this sort of hacks. I seem to bypass them by using hashes, or php's [realpath](http://us3.php.net/realpath). Thanks nevertheless

Answer (score 1):

If this is a server code - this is not a problem, as long as you keep your server secure.

If this is a client code - you are right. Someone can manipulate your code - either the binary file or the memory image (once loaded). However, this is true for any client application. You can only make it harder (by using tools like [PECompact](http://pecompact.com/pecompact.php) + [Anti-debug plugin](http://pecompact.com/ead.php) for example), but you can't achieve very strong security.

Comment: Haven't heard of these tools. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing insecure about one line with an `if` in it.

If the code is running on your server, what matters is how secure that server is. If an hacker gains access to it, it doesn't matter how complicated your code is, he will be able to circumvent it.

Similarly, if your code runs on the computer of a potential attacker (like a computer game that you want to protect), there is nothing you can do to stop the attacker. You can make his work slightly more difficult, but that's all.

You shouldn't worry about the security of one line, but of the system as a whole. If you make your code more complicated, all you did is introduce more potential for bugs. Using more complicated code is an attempt at security through obscurity, which doesn't work.

If you can't trust your computer to execute a simple `if` correctly, you can't trust it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question.

Software security techniques are imperfect, and AFAIK they pre-suppose few bugs in the compiler, and a "perfect" hardware (that is, the processor is interpreting correctly the machine code).

I am not familiar (but interested) with approaches for imperfect hardware (except of course by using redundancy or other techniques, e.g. ECC, to detect hardware errors).